# What is the error code -5 when saving in Geometry Dash?

Tags: technical-issues, geometry-dash

**PROBLEM:**
Whenever I try to backup my account in Geometry Dash, it returns text `Backup failed. Error code -5`.

**QUESTION:**
What does `Error code -5` mean, and how can I fix it?

**ATTEMPTS TO FIX THE PROBLEM:**

- If I search what `Error code -5` means in Geometry Dash on the internet, I get no results.
- If I look how to fix saving errors on Youtube, it gives a solution, but the solution doesn't work

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1, Finally someone who **shows** they tried to fix the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue, as stated by several Steam Community posts (links given through the article).

According to a developer of the game in [this Steam post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/322170/discussions/0/1620599015874377618/), you need to login again to your account (refresh login), or try to change your password from the help page if that doesn't work. [The user of this other post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/322170/discussions/0/1620599015864089513/) tried refresh login and it worked.

[A player from this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/322170/discussions/0/1499000547485406883/) says it happens after he changed his username: when you do that, you have to log off from your account, on all your devices, and then log in again with the new username.

Comment: My last save I only have 1 demon, so logging out means restarting (basically), but marked as correct if another person comes to this question.

Comment: Is it possible to change your username back and then save?